# Stripe: Send payout to customers' external bank account or debit card

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to send payout to users' added external bank account or debit card and I am getting error like `No such external account: ''`

I have added an external bank account or card using https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_accounts#external_accounts this object and I am able to add a bank account and card and when I use those details with payout then It gives an error.

What my requirement is:
User has their personal wallet where the amount is getting stored. whenever user want to withdraw fund they can add either a bank account or debit card after that they can credit their amount to their bank.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To send money you must save the user's information in Stripe. Insert the registration [button](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) into Stripe.
Then store the Stripe user id in the database:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(StripeSecretKey);

const stripeUser = await stripe.oauth.token({
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code,
});

DB.save(stripeUser.stripe_user_id); // example
```

Now you can send money this way:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(StripeSecretKey);

const stripeUser = await DB.find(id); // example

await stripe.transfers.create({
      amount,
      currency,
      destination: stripeAccount.stripeAccountId,
});
```

More about [transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers) and [oauth](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference).

Comment: How can I transfer to debit card bank account?

Comment: @MysteriousCoder similarly, to send money to another user, he must register using the button on your site, when registering he will indicate his card or bank account, and you will refer to the user id in Stripe and will send him money

Comment: I know but using transfer api I'm not able to send money to their debit card.

Comment: I wish I could. What is the difference between transfer and payout api

Comment: @MysteriousCoder payout - withdrawal of funds to your personal card or transfer to other FULL Stripe users / transfer - transfer of funds to the accounts of users registered through your application, they do not have a full-fledged account in Stripe.

Read documentation, mate)

payouts: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payouts
transfers: https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers

Comment: Yes but after registration and using my features they earn money and remains in their wallet. Now they want to withdraw money to either stripe acc or bank account using debit card. With the transfer api I'm able to transfer to their stripe account. With debit card I'm not able to transfer to their bank account.